# "Add postsharp to this project" not working

Tags: postsharp

We had a working PostSharp 6.0.16-rc reference in our .Net 4.7.1 webservice project.

We then tried upgrading to 6.0.34 which adds these two references in .csproj

```
<PackageReference Include="PostSharp" Version="6.0.34" />
<PackageReference Include="PostSharp.Redist" Version="6.0.34" />
```

But when we try to enable PostSharp for our webservice project by clicking the "Add PostSharp to this project" button , we are just shown the pop up saying

*"Install Nuget package PostSharp 6.0.34 to xxx project"*

and when we click next it says
 *"The operation has successfully completed"*

But PostSharp is still not enabled for our project...

We've tried adding the following to our csproj file (but with no effect):

```
<Import Project="$NugetPackagesPath\PostSharp.6.0.34\tools\PostSharp.targets" Condition="Exists('$NugetPackagesPath\PostSharp.6.0.34\tools\PostSharp.targets')" />
```

Any ideas on how to force-enable PostSharp?

Comment: The Import line is not needed in the project file when package references are used (PackageReference). The explicit reference to PostSharp.Redist should not be required either because it's a dependency of the PostSharp package. It's possible that migration to the new project format has broken the package references. This issue can often be fixed by completely uninstalling and reinstalling the PostSharp package.

Comment: @AlexD, Thanks for the suggestion. In the end we have ended up implementing an alternative solution, which removes the need for the postsharp reference. Thus eliminating the problem.